# Making my Django Views into a DjangoRestFramework API Endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, payment-processing

I have a payment verification View which utilizes some parameters like the secret key, and some other authentication parameters.

I would like to make the view into an API endpoint whereby i can just enter the parameter and the it returns the response.

I am familiar with making basic endpoint CRUD endpoint which has classes in models.py but this doesn't.

**P.S: I am also utilizing an external API which has the response, all i have to do is send the required parameters and then if they are correct, it returns the response.**

Views.py

```
def verify_paystack_payment(request):
    url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/262762380"

    payload = {
        "email": "email@yahoo.com",
        "amount": "10000",
        "currency": "NGN",
        "reference": "262762380",
        "metadata": {
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "display_name": "Mobile Number",
                    "variable_name": "mobile_number",
                    "value": "+2348012345678"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    files = {}

    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer **MY SECRET KEY**',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)

    return render(request, "transaction/pay.html")
```

Comment: *"I would like to make the view into an API endpoint whereby i can just enter the parameter and the it returns the response."* Could you please explain this in detail. I'm having hard time understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using from Django 1.7+ then you can use `JsonResponse`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def verify_paystack_payment(request):
    url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/262762380"

    payload = {
        "email": "email@yahoo.com",
        "amount": "10000",
        "currency": "NGN",
        "reference": "262762380",
        "metadata": {
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "display_name": "Mobile Number",
                    "variable_name": "mobile_number",
                    "value": "+2348012345678"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    files = {}

    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer **MY SECRET KEY**',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)
    return JsonResponse({"data":response.text})
```

Pre-Django 1.7 you will do like this:

```
import json 
from django.http import HttpResponse

def verify_paystack_payment(request):
    #Function code
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data":response.text}),content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: `
TypeError at /api/paystack/verify_paystack_payment/
Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
`

I get this error

Comment: Send only response content rather than response object.

Comment: I have replaced ```response``` with ```response.text``` in ```return``` step. Did it work now ?

Comment: Yes, i now get the response in my template, which is great. But the main thing i wish to achieve is to make the ability to get a DRF template using the router and then i would be able to enter dynamic reference which would then return the response